# <? print $var; ?> dangerous or not?

Tags: php

I remember someone told me a variable had to be initialized, but I'm wondering how can printing a variable can be dangerous, nobody can include my php file from a distant server, and the variable is empty when loading the php script, no ?
Then if I have this php file:

```
<?
  print $var; //or any other use of the variable like mysql...
?>
```

Is it dangerous?

Comment: `mysql_*` isn't a variable. It would be a function. Printing a variable that hasn't been declared yet isn't *dangerous*, but will just bring up errors (if error reporting is enabled!)

Comment: Please use proper `<?php // some stuff; ?>` tags

Comment: It largely depends on where the variable originates. If it isn't declared, then it's not dangerous at all, just buggy. If there is a chance that the variable will contain some user generated value, then you need to be careful to avoid xss.

Comment: This advice stems from times, when PHP had `register_globals` on per default. That setting would dump all GET, POST and REQUEST parameters as global variables. Hence a request to `script.php?var=malicious` would print `malicious`. The `register_globals` setting is nowadays widely accepted as a terrible thing and most certainly disabled.

Comment: The answer is simple and equates to the very reason why variables should be initialized in every language - default values.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

`It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array.`

Comment: instead of `print ` use `echo`.

Comment: An empty variable is not dangerous, but if it comes from `$_GET` and is not escaped, you'll have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: In fact the thing I remember is about the Boldewyn comment. My question is about a include file, I'm initializing the variable in a parent file then it is not empty I should have detailled sorry. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily dangerous, but you will get a notice that `$var` is undefined, if `error_reporting` is on.